# How to use this function to take multiple fields from and HTML form and copy it?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function copyToClipboard (text) {
  window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}
```

The form looks like this:

```
<table>
<form action="myform.php" method="post" onsubmit="return copytoClipboard()"           name="incidentCreator">
<th colspan="2">Incident Creator</th>
<tr>
<td>Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="" /></td>
<td rowspan="9"> 

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name: <input name="name" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" value="" /></td>
</tr>


function copyToClipboard (text) {
window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}
```

Somebody posted this as a solution to copy to the clipboard, but it doesn't show how to use it.  I am new to Javascript and am trying to output text from an HTML form into a format as

Can anyone show me an example of how I would take the above form data and present it ready to be copied with this Javascript function?

Comment: prompt does not have line feeds.

Comment: If anyone can just show how to use the javascript function to post data to the window ready to copy I can figure the rest out. :) thanks.

Comment: What values will be copied when you press Ctrl+C? Just the active input box or all of them?

Comment: All of them.  But if anyone can just show how to use the function above to do one, it would help.  No body has really answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to get the form in the format you want you will have to render the text yourself, based on the HTML form . use jQuery to get all the fields you need , then generate the final text and let the user copy the formatted text you rendered themself. You can use

tags to have preformated text in your html ( it will render line breaks , and tabs ,etc ...). You could use a pop up to display the final text for instance.

Anyway there is no function in javascript that automatically does what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your form to JSON string. First create JavaScript object from your fields (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery), then convert it to string using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON.